# What is X.509 and how does one use it?

Tags: web-services, rest, public-key-encryption, pem

What is X.509?

How does one use it in REST web service for authentication?

Comment: This question is too broad.  I suggest you do some basic research on what X.509 is and then try and ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509)

As stated above in comments your question is too bread.
I assume that you mean authetication using SSL with Client Authentication. But may be you mean something else...

Anyway, Basically you need to configure SSL with Client Authentication.
Most servlet containers (like Tomcat) or Web Servers (like Apache) can do it for you.

Here's guide how to [configure SSL in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). Pay attention that `clientAuth` should be true,